# Can not connect Remote Desktop to windows server after restart

Tags: google-cloud-platform, remote-desktop

I have a server Google Cloud, it has been good working some years, but recently there was a problem, after restart server, I can not connect to its remote desktop, the prompt messagebox content is as follows:

```
Remote Desktop can’t connect to the remote computer for one of these reasons:
1.Remote access to the server is not enabled
2.The remote computer is turned off
3.The remote computer is not available on the network
```

But i check it is still on and has network connection, anybody help me?

update 1:  I found the reason is port 3389 could not connect, but I tried the commands on command line still can't open port 3389

update 2: my team decided to destroy this server, close topic

Comment: update: I found the reason is port 3389 could not connect, but I tried the commands on command line still can't open port 3389

Comment: https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/troubleshooting/troubleshooting-rdp

Comment: I tried this, and here are the results in "Check the OS configuration": 1,2,3,4,5, 8: pass; 6,7: cannot reset to default

Comment: Regarding your comment. My link is to help you debug/solve this issue. If you have tests that you performed, edit your question with details. Providing a list of numbers is not helpful - your question should be self-contained without requiring analysis of an external document.